# Background task at launch will suspend the app after random time

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm working on an app that connect to accessory via bluetooth and I've implemented a state preservation and restoration if an app crashed to restore the connection in background.

When the app crash/closed by iOS via `jetsamevent`, it will be relaunched again and in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, I've implemented a background task to give the app more time to re-connect to the previous peripheral, it will give the app ~3 minute of scanning for peripheral.

Here is the code I'm using for starting and ending the background task:

```
var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

func registerBackgroundTask() {
    backgroundTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler {
        [unowned self] in
        self.endBackgroundTask()
    }
}

func endBackgroundTask() {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
    backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}
```

I'm calling `registerBackgroundTask` at launch (in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`)

The issue is that at some point, the `endBackgroundTask` get called and the app (it seems) move to suspend state and come back to background state again after a random time, sometimes 3 min, 15 min or 3 hours.

Note:
I've used [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) to implement the state preservation and restoration, Section `State Preservation and Restoration`

Comment: If you have implemented state restoration and correctly reinitialise scanning on your central then there is no reason to begin a background task. Discovery of a matching peripheral will relaunch your app for restoration and then you will get a call to your delegate method.

Comment: @Paulw11 You are right, but I've faced an issue where the app does not get enough time to scan for peripheral and it wasn't connect to the app at all, because of that I've used background task, to extend the scanning time and to make sure the app has enough time to re-connect to the peripheral

Comment: You shouldn't need any time to scan for the peripheral; the very reason that your app was relaunched is because a peripheral matching an active scan was detected by iOS and is this peripheral will be delivered to your delegate immediately after you re-createnyour cbcentral. Similarly if you have a pending connect; you can examine the ios device log to see your app being relaunched